# AWS No ephemeral device on t1.micro ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am launching a t1.micro instance using this command

```
ec2-run-instances ami-a29943cb -t t1.micro -z us-east-1c -k prod --block-device-mapping=sdb=ephemeral0 --block-device-mapping=sdc=ephemeral1 -K <key> -C <cert>
```

Although instance is launched successfully, but I see no ephemeral device on login. Anybody face similar problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micro instances do not come with ephemeral instance store devices.